# Add array to jagged array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I want to create a dynamic jagged array with dynamic data. The problem is that a part of the jagged array is only a two column type and the rest of it is a 4 column type. Code is in C#.

```
public static Object[][] my_array = new Object[20][];
public static void LoadData()
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
     {
         my_array[i]    = new Object[20];
         my_array[i][0] = "Data1";
         my_array[i][1] = "Data2";
         my_array[i][2] = "Data3";
         my_array[i][3] = "Data4";
         my_array[i][4] = new Object[100];

         for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
         {
             my_array[i][4][j] = new Object[200];
             my_array[i][4][j][0] = "SubData1";
         }
         my_array[i][5] = "Data6";
     }
 }
```

I get following error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error    CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Is this even possible to do this in C#?

Comment: Rather than arrays, I suggest you use `List<T>` structures, they will give you dynamic flexibility.
If you have elements of different types, then maybe you should use a class with typed and named members.

Comment: The compiler does not know that `my_array[i][4]` is an `Object[]` instance, you have to cast it

Comment: This seems more like a XY problem. What problem are you actually trying to solve? What you are trying seems pretty dangerous because sometimes at `my_array[i][j]` is a `string` and sometimes there is another `object[]`. Do you want to parse some kind of JSON or XML? Because there are parsers for that.

Comment: This smells of using arrays to avoid defining a class.

Comment: I love the smell of xy when i get home from work, as @bommelding said just define some concrete classes uses list<T> where its needed, and make your life easier

Comment: i, j is ALWAYS will be int type. @Freggar no, its big data, from other documents which stored array in array.  Of course I could create second  array and then I finnish messing with second array set data to first array  my_array[i][4] = my_second_array;

Comment: Is the data you are loading from structured, or is it random, ie unknown at runtime?

Comment: structured, there is some parts only int, others only string, some others bool type, using jagged type array is most easiest way to manage, but creating array in array like in my example, seems impossible, unless I assign to specific first array element second array, that seems to be solution.

Comment: Sorry for double post, but I cannot edit my previous post, reading inserted second array is not solution since, it throws error that is wrong type.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast it to Array before applying indexing, like:

```
var array = (Object[]) my_array[i][4];
```

Comment: Using my example where I should put this?

Comment: @JonZ 
`for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
         {
             var array = (Object[]) my_array[i][4];
             array[j] = new Object[200];
             var mySecondArray = (Object[])array[j];
             mySecondArray[0] = "SubData1";
         }`